# Graceful Riak force-replace

Tags: database, nosql, riak

This is something reading the docs over and over did not clarify for me.

a. I have an unhealthy, inaccessible node - let's call it Node A - which I want to remove from the Riak cluster and replace with a new, healthy Node B.

b. I want to do this while minimizing cluster traffic to "repopulate" Node B with the data Node A was supposed to have.

c. I assume I can do this by starting Node B even from an **hour-old backup** of Node A's data

d. However, since the name of the node changes (from Node A to Node B), I have to first `join` Node B as an entirely new node on the cluster, and then use `cluster force-replace` to replace Node A with Node B.



My question is - would this process result in:

a. The existing backed-up data on Node B being respected and only the gaps from the last hour being filled in by `Read Repair`

b. Or, the backed-up data on Node B being ignored completely (since the backup is for "Node A" while the running node is "Node B") and Node B being flushed with traffic from other nodes trying to populate it with data **from scratch**.

Maybe I'm just not reading something right or spending too much time thinking about this. Let me know how this would work.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dev:

What `riak-admin cluster force-replace` does is reassign the ownership of the partitions to the joining node.  You would end up at (A): the existing data would be used and the remaining hour would be filled in via read repair.

There are some documentation changes in the pipeline that should make this process a little clearer.  Sorry for any confusion you had.

Hope this helps,
Charlie Voiselle
cvoiselle@basho.com

Comment: Great. Thanks. That sounds about right considering everything else has seemed nice and elegant so far.